# Returning a button to default color

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm customizing button colors etc, and I want to be able to reset the form to default colors. I know what I have to do ,as I have found the answer when googling, but `UseVisualStyleBackColor` is not working?!?! I am looping through buttons, and Visual Studio underlines the command.

```
this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
  {
    c.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    c.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
  }
}
```

The error received is

> CS1061    'Control' does not contain a definition for 'UseVisualStyleBackColor' and no extension method 'UseVisualStyleBackColor' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I try and access a button direct I get the same error?

Comment: `UseVisualStyleBackColor` is a property of `ButtonBase`, not `Control`.

Comment: `((Button)c).UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;`  Or fix your loop: `foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {`

Comment: Cheers. I tried casting C to a button, but didn't wrap the brackets around them both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if (c is Button)
  {
     var button = (Button)c;
     button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
     button.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but the buttons are now the same colour as the form, they should be a shade darker. I thought that was what `UseVisualStyleBackColor` was for?

Comment: Just swap the lines with `UseVisualStyleBackColor` and `BackColor` :). Here is explanation how `UseVisualStyleBackColor` works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506641/when-i-change-a-net-buttons-backcolor-back-to-its-original-value-it-doesnt-l.

Comment: Solved my issue. set the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` after changing the color

Comment: Our messages must have been posted at the same time @Miamy

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *Linq* (`.OfType<Button>()`) to filter out buttons:

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) 
{
    btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    btn.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any version of C#, you can use type casting:

```
((Button)c).UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Starting with C# 7 you can use [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) (try to cast it + on success, assign result to new variable):

```
if (c is Button b))
{
    b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    b.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Learning so much!

Answer (score 0):

Slight issue in the order of the code need for it to work. Had to redorder the setting of the colour and the Visual Style....

```
            this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button b)
            {
                b.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
                b.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            }
        }
```